# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Hi guys i have a problem with passing some data from a form to another so i tried to create functions that return these values and call them in the other form The problem is that i get this error message : *An object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property.*
Can you help me pls !

In a form:

```
    public string getTextBox1()
    {
        return myTextBox1.ToString();
    }

    public string getTextBox2()
    {
        return myTextBox2.ToString();
    }

    public string getTextBox3()
    {
        return myTextBox3.ToString();
    }

    public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        borne.borneH = myTextBox1.ToString();
        borne.borneB = myTextBox2.ToString();
        borne.codeP = myTextBox3.ToString();


        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), borne);
    }
```

In the other form:

```
    public List<Borne> buildObjectGraph()
    {
        var myBorne = new List<Borne>();

        myBorne.Add(new Borne() { borneH = ABPage.getTextBox1(), borneB = ABPage.getTextBox1(), codeP = ABPage.getTextBox1()  });

        return myBorne;
    }
```

Btw i tried the NavigationService for data transfer but i got the error:

> the name 'NavigationService' does not exist in the current context

Comment: And exactly *where* does this error occur? If you want to call a method on another "Form", you need an instance of that form to do so unless it is marked `static` (which is exactly what the message says).

Comment: The error occurs in this part borneH = ABPage.getTextBox1() and if the function getTextBox() is static i get the same error in: return myTextBox.ToString(); I'm new to c# and wp8.1 development so help me pls

Comment: If you are new to C#, you might want to start with a book or tutorial to get the basics down. But you need to pass the instance of ABPage that is running into whatever this other form is (via constructor, property, or parameter to `buildObjectGraph`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class that defines the methods `getTextBox1`, `getTextBox2` and `getTextBox3`. You can then access these methods via the instance like `MyInstanceOfABPage.getTextBox1()`. You cannot access these methods via the class name as they are not static.

Comment: Hi Wosi thank you for your answer, the problem is that when i create an instance of the methods i "can't / don't know how" get these instances that i passed using Frame.Navigate !  I'm new to c# and wp8.1 development so help me pls

Comment: Look for some tutorials that show you how the MVVM pattern works and how you can pass values through different ViewModels. It's a big topic. But it's well documented.